# Dynamic field generation jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I have created a form with the option to dynamically add fields with excellent code help from http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/. The only issue is that I want the fields to generate without also showing new 'Add' and 'Remove' buttons. How should I go about doing this? I can get it to work by having the buttons displayed underneath the field with a new `<div>` but I want them to be to the right of the field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first')
                    .attr('id', 'device' + newNum)
                    .attr('name', 'device' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 3)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

                $('#input' + num).remove();
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    </script>
```

```
    <div> Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></div>
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
    Device(s):  <input type="text" name="device1" id="device1" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove" />
     </div>
```

Comment: I you want to show the buttons on the left, this is a css question. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: I have them displayed on the right, but when the btnAdd click function is invoked, it also generates a new Add and Delete button in addition to the new field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are cloning the whole div, which contains the two buttons. So you have to remove those two. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GF3A/

I added this:

```
newElem.find(":button").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code :

```
newElem.find('input[type="button"]').remove();
```

See the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/534T9/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>
 <div> Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></div>
 <div style="float:left;">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Device(s):  <input type="text" name="device1" id="device1" />
    </div>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left;">
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove" />
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript "src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var _getNum = function() {
                return $('.clonedInput').length;
            }
            var _updateButtons = function() {
                var num     = _getNum();
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', num <= 1 ? 'disabled' : false);
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', num >= 3 ? 'disabled' : false);
            }
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = _getNum();
                var newNum  = num + 1;

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first')
                    .attr('id', 'device' + newNum)
                    .attr('name', 'device' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                _updateButtons();
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num     = _getNum();
                $('#input' + num).remove();
                _updateButtons();
            });

            _updateButtons();
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```